# Ubuntu Touch on HTC HD2 Leo

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to get a version of the great Ubuntu Touch for HTC HD2 Leo?
HTC Leo seems to be an unsupported device?

Answer (score 2):

I have started an Ubuntu Touch FAQ in order to have some answers to frequent questions available:

please look here: [On which devices does this Developer Preview run?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#On_which_devices_does_this_Developer_Preview_run.3F)

and here: [Can you make it run on my device xyz as well?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Can_you_make_it_run_on_my_device_xyz_as_well.3F)

Answer (score 0):

At this point the HTC HD2 is indeed unsupported. You can however run Ubuntu on it (not touch), but someone could port Ubuntu Touch to the HD2.